# How to save username and password in phone cache

Tags: android

I have a user login app, which takes email, and password from user. I want to save the email and password in phone cache so user does not have to type again. Is there any way to save data in Android cache.

Comment: With "Android cache" you mean application cache space? Yes you could, but why not use SharedPreferences?

Comment: yes in cache space. can you show me how to save with shared preferences.

Comment: you should definitely go with the SharedPreferences. because while your GC run your cache of your app will be blank.

for that you can take reference from provided link for the save and retrieve the data from sharedPreferance. http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/content/android-sharedpreferences-example/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to use `SharedPreference` for that which save your data while your application in your device. After uninstall the app from device the data will be remove.

1) Save Data to `SharedPreference` :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("UserData", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("username", username);
editor.putString("password", password);
editor.commit();
```

2) Retrieve data from `SharedPreference`:

```
SharedPreference prefs = getSharedPreferences("UserData", MODE_PRIVATE);
String username = prefs.getString("username","");
String pwd = prefs.getString("password","");
```

Comment: totally insecure saving password inside SharedPreferences

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SharedPreferences` for that..

```
SharedPreferences wmbPreference1,wmbPreference2;    
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

//wmbPreference for Shared Prefs that lasts forever
wmbPreference1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);  

//installsp for Shared Prefs that lasts only just once each time program is running
wmbPreference2 =getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("install_code_prefs",Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

To save values

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = wmbPreference1.edit();
editor.putString("MYKEY", "12345");
editor.commit();
```

You can retrieve the values like

```
String Phonenumber = wmbPreference1.getString("MYKEY", "");
```

where **MYKEY** is the keyname by which you can identify the value..

Answer (score 1):

SharedPreferences for this kind of type are **much** simpler than use application cache.

For more info about SharedPreferences read documentation, you can have SharedPreferences related to an activity or to an activity (it changes just where it will be saved.)

To access to the default sharedpreference you will use the static method of `PreferenceManager` named `getDefaultSharedPreferece` which takes as argument the context (`this` if you are inside an Activity)

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Now using this SharedPreferences instance you can read everything which is saved inside this file.

To read you will use the methods sharedPreferences.get(String/Int/Long/Float etc. etc.).

Example to read the email and password of the user, you could write

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String email = sharedPreferences.getString("email", null);
String password = sharedPreferences.getString("password", null");
```

> ("password", null)

1. "password": will be the key, in fact shared preferences are saved as `key=value` pair, so you should use the same key when you read and when you write to be sure you update/read the same value.
2. null: It's the defaultValue, the variable `password` will be `null` if Android failed to found the key inside the file.

Right now, if you execute this code email and password will be `null` since you didn't add nothing.

To add something in the file you should use `SharedPreferences.Editor` which contains all methods to edit key-value pairs. To create this object you will call method `edit()` in our sharedPreference variable.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
```

now we will use our `editor` variable to save our data.

Like read, it has methods like put(String/Int/Long) (the same of read just with put)

So we want to save email and password of the user, since are strings we will use `putString`

```
editor.putString("password", "helloWorld");
```

It's similar to what we have see above, but with a difference: While `password` is still the key to use (note: it's the same of the read line) the second argument is the **value**, as the name says it's what we should write as password. It this case it will save `helloWorld` as password.

The same for email, replace `helloWorld` with your variable which contains the password.

Remember, you **should** call `.commit()` (of editor) when you are ready to save values in the file. (if you don't, you will not update the values inside the file.)

Your code will look like this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("email", "helloWorld@gmail.com");
editor.putString("password", "helloWorld");
editor.commit();
```

Now, when you execute again the read code you will read in the email `helloWorld@gmail.com` and in password `helloWorld`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for this. Something like [this](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/content/android-sharedpreferences-example/)

Comment: Plz can you show me in code im very new to android and java.

Comment: @user3605640 I've already left a link http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/content/android-sharedpreferences-example/

Answer (score 0):

**1.Declare these variables/constants in your class**

```
private SharedPreferences prefs = null;
public static final String MY_PREFERENCE = "my_preference";// preference name
public static final String USER_NAME = "username"; // key for username
public static final String PASSWORD = "passoword";//key for password
```

**2.now save user and password in you method**

```
prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCE, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(USER_NAME, username);
        editor.putString(PASSWORD, password);
        editor.commit();
```

Where **username, password** are the strings you got from user input.

Comment: thank you so much. i have to get email and password from the edit text boxes. Please show me some lines for that I'm new to java and android.

Comment: @user3605640 I have updated answer to read values from User inputs