# Android app forgets login on Resume

Tags: java, android

I develop an Android app that starts with a MainActivity that is a login screen. After a successful login it inits the data depending of the login and starts the default activity.

- That works great when starting the app from scratch.
- When the app was in background before and it is resumed, then it directly runs the last activity (not the Login activity) which is great.
- But sometimes - I think when being in background for a long time - I open the app, it starts as expected from the last activity but the data is not initialized according to the login. It is like it dropped all app data in memory but still does not start from scratch.

Are there different kinds of resuming an app? Any way to prevent that?

Comment: If activities are not active, they are placed on the activity stack. if the app needs to free memory, it removes the last active activity on this stack, so do not depend on active actvities. Save your state to SharedPreferences and retrieve it upon resuming the activity. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: How are you currently saving your login values? SharedPreferences could work, or a singleton depending on how persistent you want things to be.

Comment: Currently I use a global variable in memory to store the login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're facing the same issue, the fact is, storing login data in your Application class is not a good idea (as you can see, lot of people are saying to keep your data in your Application class but don't do that).

If it's sensitive data that you need to re-use later in your Activity, there is a possibility that android kill your App when it's in background, I was able to reproduce it by running an emulator with low memory, put your app in background and launch lot of other applications, and if you put a log in your `onCreate()` method in your Application class you will see it called at a random moment. At this moment all your fields will become `null` if they are not reinitialized in `onCreate()`

You can use `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` of your Activity which will be called when the app is killed/restored
There is lot of solutions to fix that, but no ideal way I think. just do it following your need.

Answer (score 1):

If you're storing information in a static variable and the class were unloaded, you'd lose this information.

For global or session information, it'll have to be persisted to a datastore such as an SQLite database or SharedPreferences.

For data specific to an instance of an Activity that you wish to remember and restore from, override `onSavedInstanceState` to save to a `Bundle` and [restore](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) in `onCreate`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not caching your credentials, so when the app gets killed or the activity is destroyed you will lose that state.

[android: how to save username and password in phone cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23628690/android-how-to-save-username-and-password-in-phone-cache)

gives a good example of how to do this with Shared Prefs

Answer (score 0):

Use SharedPreferences to save ur data

> **Initialization**

Application shared preferences can be fetched using `getSharedPreferences()` method.You also need an editor to edit and save the changes in shared preferences. The following code can be used to get application shared preferences.

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
Editor editor = pref.edit();
```

> **Storing Data**

You can save data into shared preferences using editor. All the primitive data types like booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings are supported. Call `editor.apply()` in order to save changes to shared preferences.

```
editor.putBoolean("key_name", true); // Storing boolean - true/false
editor.putString("key_name", "string value"); // Storing string
editor.putInt("key_name", "int value"); // Storing integer
editor.putFloat("key_name", "float value"); // Storing float
editor.putLong("key_name", "long value"); // Storing long

editor.apply(); // apply changes
```

> **Retrieving Data**

Data can be retrived from saved preferences by calling getString() (For string) method. Remember this method should be called on Shared Preferences not on Editor.

```
/ returns stored preference value
// If value is not present return second param value - In this case null
pref.getString("key_name", null); // getting String
pref.getInt("key_name", null); // getting Integer
pref.getFloat("key_name", null); // getting Float
pref.getLong("key_name", null); // getting Long
pref.getBoolean("key_name", null); // getting boolean
```

> **Clearing / Deleting Data**

```
editor.remove("name"); // will delete key name
editor.remove("email"); // will delete key email

editor.apply(); // commit changes
```

**OR Following will clear all the data from shared preferences:**

```
editor.clear();
editor.apply(); // commit changes
```

check this [Android User Session Management using Shared Preferences](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/) for example
hope to be helpful